# should I use multiple aws instances for multiple worker node or multiple VM inside one instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, vagrant, devops, orchestration

I am studying kubernetes.
If I want to build a cluster consisting of 3 worker nodes and 1 master node in AWS then -

- Should I create 4 Virtual Machine inside one Instance (Many cpu cores and Large RAM) ? or
- I should create 4 AWS instances (small cpu cores and small RAM) as worker nodes

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that ec2 instances are already VMs running in larger machines, and given the additional complexity of setting up your own vms inside an ec2 instance, I would highly recommend going for the second approach.

This also has the added benefit that auto-scaling your cluster (i.e. automatically scaling the number of workers) comes out of the box if you use the aws-cluster-autoscaler.